# resolving multiple inclusion issues

Tags: c

I had such situation.
I have `main.c` file, and another `operations.c` and `operations.h` file.
Clearly `operations.c` includes `operations.h`,
`main.c` includes `operations.h` too.

But then I came to situation that I would need to refer to functions implemented in `main.c` from `operations.c`. But when I put `#include "main.c"` in `operations.c` I got errors about multiple definitions.

How do you deal with such situations?

I encountered in some code, one was using some approach. He had `"global.h"` file which would include `operations.h` and `main.h` (I had to create `main.h` manually). Then from `main.c` and `operations.c` you would just include `global.h`. I think this way multiple definition errors dissapeared. What do you think - is this one of the ways to deal with the issue I mentioned above?

Comment: use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is one way, yes.

Another is of course to remove the functions other than `main()` from `main.c`, and put them in a separate module, with its own implementation (`.c`) and header (`.h`) files.

It's often a good idea to use protection against multiple inclusion, too, i.e. at the top of each header, do something like:

```
#if !defined FOO_H_
#define FOO_H_
```

then at the bottom, after all the declarations and so on, have:

```
#endif /* FOO_H_ */
```

Of course, `FOO_H_` should be the actual filename, i.e. `OPERATIONS_H_` in your `operations.h` file and so on.

Comment: One more question please. Now I am getting this warning: "src/operations.c:1048: warning: implicit declaration of function 'postMainMenu'"; postMainMenu - is defined in main.c. Should it be like this? (the warning?)

Answer (score 0):

Declare prototypes for the functions you want in a header and include that. They should be *defined* exactly once (in, say, `main.c`) but you can reference them in many places with declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> But then I came to situation that I would need to refer to functions implemented in main.c from operations.c.

If you have such needs, then something is fundamentally flawed with your program design. You should change it to an object-oriented model, where each module (h file + c file) is autonomous and doesn't know or care about anything else but its own specific purpose. Particularly, not a single file in your project should have a dependency leading to main.c.

> He had "global.h" file which would include operations.h and main.h

This leads to something very bad called *[tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)* all over your program, where every code module depends on another module. You should write C modules with object-oriented design, making them autonomous, while using *[private encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)* as much as possible.